# Count Down 1 Day for Each Row mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I added a column to my mysql table called `dateAdded` which should hold a time value for each row. I want to add a time value into each row in the column, but I want it to count down by one day. I used:

`UPDATE products set dateAdded=DATE_ADD('2015-06-15 11:31:31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

but it just counts up one day and displays the exact same day for all the values in the column.

How can I add the date to the column and have it increment down by one day for each row?

Comment: Do you want the rows randomly updated or is there an inherent ordering  for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE products 
JOIN (select @date := '2015-06-15 11:31:31') d
SET dateAdded = (@date := @date - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Although this would probably work in practice, it relies on the order of evaluation of the rows.  The proper way to guarantee the ordering is using `order by`.  Unfortunately, `update` does not support `order by` with `join`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as a single statement:

```
UPDATE products p
    SET dateAdded = date_sub(cast('2015-06-15 11:31:31' as datetime),
                             interval (@rn := coalesce(@rn + 1, 1) day
                            )
    ORDER BY <appropriate column for the ordering of the data>;
```